# What would be the simplest way to gather all database queries run during a single HTTP request?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

We're using SQLAlchemy and FastAPI. Because of fast moving requirements and some lax practices, we have a few endpoints that are running way more queries than needed (the classic n+1 problem, basically), with all the consequences for performance we all know about. I'd like to tackle this problem, but as usual, good diagnostics is key. Looking through logs, I can find a few instances of requests that take too long, and these are usually in endpoints that are indeed making a lot of requests. However, I'm only seeing the ones that are going over the threshold we set for notifications of slow requests. I could lower that threshold and get more, but because of some external limitations (specifically, we need to query an external service that takes a few seconds to respond, we do cache the response but when the cached value expires that makes some requests take a long time with no relationship to our db query issue) lowering the notification threshold for slow requests would flood our notifications with false positives.

So I'm thinking we need a way to see how many queries we make. And also, ideally, *what* queries me make. What I would like is that at request end, we take a list of all the db queries made during this request, count them, and if it's over a certain number, we send a notification.

The current way I'm thinking of doing this is get them from the logger. Just look at all logged elements with name sqlalchemy.engine.Engine for current request, and count them. This should work, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this more a problem related to background tasks? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/

Comment: I honestly don't see how background tasks would help with this.

Comment: Then I do not understand what you're doing and why are you trying to achieve it. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I basically want to know how many SQL queries were emitted during the executing of a given endpoint. The solution I currently have, which I'm unhappy with, is I added a filter to the logger, and accumulate in a context var the count of every call to log a query. It _works_, but it's just not very pretty.

Comment: Why don't you add it to the query? Every time you run a query, you also run another query that increments a counter in a table reserved for `statistics`